# How to handle posts asking multiple independent questions

Tags: discussion, questions, flagging

The Stack Exchange question and answer format breaks down when multiple discrete questions are posed in one post. Either answers must address each question, or they fail to completely meet the expectations of the posting user.

In [this particular case](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80821/pros-and-cons-in-hardwood-floor-sanding-choices-and-remove-quarter-rounders-in-r), the poser was advised to break down an [earlier post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80788/what-is-the-recommendation-polyurethane-application-when-refinishing-hardwood-fl) that asked five different questions. The second post, however, still asks several questions both in the title and the post body.

Is this simply a "too broad" scenario? What's the right approach to moderation from the community?

Answer (score 2):

If the user was asked to separate the question into multiple question, and the resulting question still asked multiple questions. Then the user should be asked again to separate the questions.

There's not much else that can be done, apart from editing out all but a single question. Which *may* be appropriate, if the user continues the behavior.